# Recurring payments using Paypal Merchant SDK or Paypal REST API

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

Everything does not look good with the Paypal APIs. [Paypal Merchant API](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/tree/namespace-php5.3) seems to be deprecated , but most of the examples and functionality is referring to Marchant SDK.For example take [Recurring](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_cc/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox). REST API does not provide any example of Recurring Payments !

In what context this API is deprecated ? I am looking for recurring payments done for "Paypal Payments Advanced" account type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to implement Recurring Billing with PayPal Payments Advanced you'll want to look at the Payflow platform APIs. here is a good place to get started:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/recurring-billing/

Comment: Thanks @KevinG any resource for php ? . What I see http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#payflow-gateway is only java/oscommerce  support.What I have explored untill now is that none of the sdks provide complete interaction with paypal. Each sdk provides certain level of feature.

Comment: http://ccaples.com/chad/pf_sdk_v2/downloads/pf_php_sdk_v1.zip Here is a Payflow SDK written in php. I provide this as-is with no warranty of any kind. Use it at your own risk and be sure to replace any existing authentication credentials with your own.

Comment: Thanks for complete demo , I ll go through thoroughly

Comment: Do they have a php sdk for payflow?

Comment: @PP_GOPSMTS_KevinG , I have a question -- Could you provide a Payflow SDK written in C#? I would be eternally grateful :)